# How to position an element inside a div at the same height as another element in the same div

Tags: html, css

I want to set the position of the element inside the div at the same height as another element in the same div. Initially all the elements inside the div are placed at correct height inside div for the below code,

```
<div class="main">
    <a href="link"> link </a>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div>
                <button><svg class="icon"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    white-space: nowrap;

    > * {
        display: block;
    }
    a {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .menu {
        margin-left: 8px;
        .icon {
            width: 14px;
        }
    }
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.contents {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
  }
```

Now when in order to have a clickable area around the svg, i add class "icon_area" to the div containing svg as below,

```
<div class="icon_area">
    <button><svg class="icon"></button>
</div>
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    .icon_area {
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

After doing so the element inside div ( before  appears side by side but then  is slightly above ).

**Expected:** Both the elements to be of same height.
Could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Comment: Could you not simply set a height against both divs?

Comment: please share a working fiddle

Comment: where's the `.contents` element ? can you share a working SO snippet ( not fiddle ) that replicates your problem ? otherwise we cannot help you

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it is "raised" by the 10px `padding` valus. Since `.wrapper` has`position: relative`, you could just add `bottom: -10px` to make up for that (or `margin-bottom: -10px`)

Comment: tried and its moving the svg icon to the bottom. thanks